# Does ASN.1 supports some form of inheritance?

Tags: inheritance, asn.1

For example, let's say I define something like this:

```
World-Schema DEFINITIONS AUTOMATIC TAGS ::= 
 BEGIN
  Human ::= SEQUENCE {
   name UTF8String,
   first-words UTF8String DEFAULT "Hello World",
   age  INTEGER (1..150) OPTIONAL,
   height INTEGER (120..200)
 }
END
```

Now I want to define a `ShortHuman`, which is exactly the same but `height` is limited to 150. Can I somehow reuse the already defined `Human` and refine that description?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure how you define inheritance, but you can use Human to define ShortHuman as follows:

ShortHuman::= Human (WITH COMPONENTS {height (120..150)})

This will restrict the height as you desire.

Actually, it is probably better to use the following:

ShortHuman::= Human (WITH COMPONENTS {..., height (120..150)})

A partial specification does not place any restrictions on components not listed, while the full specification (without the ..., ) would require optional components not listed (such as age) to be absent.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I was looking for. Maybe inheritance it's not the most fitting name in this case.

Answer (score 1):

ASN.1 doesn't itself use the term "inheritance".  Annex C, "Rules for type and value Compatibility" in X.680 talks about the relationships between ASN.1 types, if you want to read it.

You could use parameterization to define Human and ShortHuman like so:

```
HumanBase { INTEGER : maxHeight } ::= SEQUENCE {
   name UTF8String,
   first-words UTF8String DEFAULT "Hello World",
   age  INTEGER (1..150) OPTIONAL,
   height INTEGER (120..maxHeight)
}

Human ::= HumanBase { 200 }

ShortHuman ::= HumanBase { 150 }
```

Parameterization is a commonly used ASN.1 feature for "reusing" definitions that fit some pattern.  Note that you can also have parameters that are types, so you could, as an unlikely example, use different string types for "name" in type Human vs. Short Human.  X.683 covers parameterization.